# Remove ticks from 1st axis on 2nd axis in MATLAB when using plotyy and axes limits

Tags: matlab, plot, multiple-axes

I am trying to use MATLABs `plotyy` function in combination with y-axes limits like that

```
x = [4:2:14 18];
y1 = [86; 87; 88; 89; 89.3; 89.6; 89.7];
y2 = [15; 35; 63; 99; 143; 195; 323];
width = .36;
axes = plotyy(x-width, y1, x+width, y2, @(x,y) bar(x,y,width,'b'), @(x,y) bar(x,y,width,'r'));
set(axes(1), 'ylim', [85 90]);
set(axes(1), 'ytick', 85:90);
set(axes(2), 'ytick', 0:50:400);
set(axes,'xtick',x)
```

and this is the result:

[image: The plotyy result with wrong ticks]

What I want to get rid of are the ticks on the 2nd y-axis which don't have a tick label. They seem to be leftovers from the 1st y-axis. How can I remove them or avoid them to be drawn?

Comment: Can you post a runnable example?

Comment: @LuisMendo Sure, I added some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372123/drawing-the-top-axis-box-line), what you should do is:

```
set(axes(1),'Box','off');
```

However, this also removes the top line. If you need to keep the line, see the answer to that question as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
box((axes(1),'off')
```