# How to make the same scale, limit and tick of 2 yaxis left and right in matlab plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-hg2

Below is the code that I used to have the same scale for both y axis in MATLAB plot:

```
%% Additions by Dev-iL:
date = 1:10;
z = 4*randn(3,10);
spread = 0.2*sum(z,1);
figure();
%% Original code by RSerrano:
ax(2) = subplot(2,1,2);
% z = horzcat(zscore,signal1,signal2); % Dev-iL
  yyaxis left
  plot(date,z,'LineWidth',0.5);
  ylabel('Z-score(residuals)');
  set(ax(2),'YColor',[0 0 0],'YDir','normal');
  ax(2).YLimMode = 'manual';
  ax(2).YLim = [-8 8];
  ax(2).YTickMode = 'manual';
  ax(2).YTick = -8:2:8;

co1 = get(gca,'ColorOrder'); 
% Change to new colors.
set(gca, 'ColorOrder', [0.83 0.82 0.78; 0 0.5 0; 0.47 0.67 0.19],...
         'NextPlot', 'replacechildren');
co1 = get(gca,'ColorOrder'); 
plot(date,z,'LineWidth',0.3);

z2 = spread;
yyaxis right
plot(date,z2,'Color',[0.31 0.31 0.31], 'LineWidth',0.5);
xlabel('Date');
ylabel('Spread(USD)');
title(['Spread and Trade Signals']);
legend('Z-score','Signal1', ...
'Signal2','Spread', ...
'Location','NE');
set(ax(2),'YColor',[0 0 0],'YDir','normal');

ax(2).YTick = -8:2:8;
axis tight
grid on
```

This results in:

[image: Example output by Dev-iL]

How I can make the `ylim` and `ytick` of left y axis the same with right y axis? or how can I apply the `ylim` and `ytick` of left y axis to the right y axis?

Comment: When posting example code, make sure it's at least runnable. See this for additional instruction: [mcve].

Comment: Not minding the example code that I posted(by the way, that's my personal code and it worked for me), would you know how to make the ylim of the right y axis similar to left y axis? I'm getting frustrated with MATLAB, it's not really user friendly. Many thanks.

Comment: The code is ok, but you have some undefined variables: `date`, `z` and `z2`. It would've been easy to make the above code runnable if you just added something like `date = 1:10; z = 10*randn(3,10); z2 = z;`. In any case I'm working on a solution for you. For now, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30381089/3372061).

Comment: date, z and z2 are array.  no need to run the code that I specified. or perhaps, create a value. What I am just asking is it possible to re-apply the ylim set from left y axis to right y axis? I will use the code for almost 20,000 matlab plot and it's very tedious if I will fix the scale of both left and right y axis of each plot one by one. I tried to use for left y axis the ylim(ax(2),[-10 10]) and use it again it right y axis but it didn't work. It seems like I need to fix the scale of each plot manually. Thanks

Comment: Rest assured - you won't have to do this manually. When you post code that allegedly causes some problem, it has to be runnable or else others can't reporoduce your problem and can't help you - simple as that. Note that this is not my personal opinion but the rules of SO.

Comment: I took out the code I specified to have more focus on my question, since my question (I think) is generic anyway and no need to specify the code that I am using.

Comment: Nononono - it was critical that you had your code here, please put it back before somebody closes this question because it's now "unclear what you're asking". Either the code or at least a screenshot of what's wrong is something you should have.

Comment: @RSerrano Could you add your original code back, please? It is very helpful for future readers to see your original example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the `yyaxis` you're using, I'd assume you have R2016a and therefore using HG2.

As an alternative to `yyaxis`, assuming you just want to have the same ticks on both sides, you can just copy the axes and set the position of the  y axis to be on the right (as demonstrated in a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30381089/3372061)):

```
hR = axes('ylim', [y(1) y(end)],'XTick', [], 'YTick', y,'YAxisLocation', 'right',...
            'XTickLabel',[]);
```

Using a slightly rearranged version of your code:

```
%% Definitions:
date = 1:10;
z = 4*randn(3,10);
z2 = 0.2*sum(z,1);
y = -8:2:8;
%% Create the figure:
figure(); hL = gca;
set(hL, 'ColorOrder', [0.83 0.82 0.78; 0 0.5 0; 0.47 0.67 0.19],...
        'NextPlot', 'replacechildren');
plot(date, z,'LineWidth',0.5); hold on;
plot(date, z2,'Color',[0.31 0.31 0.31], 'LineWidth',0.5);
%% Customize plots:
grid on
xlabel(hL,'Date');
ylabel(hL,'Z-score(residuals)');
hL.YLimMode = 'manual';
hL.YLim = [y(1) y(end)];
hL.YTickMode = 'manual';
hL.YTick = y;

title(['Spread and Trade Signals']);
legend(hL,'Z-score','Signal1', ...
'Signal2','Spread', ...
'Location','NE');

hR = axes('ylim', [y(1) y(end)],'XTick', [], 'YTick', y,'YAxisLocation', 'right',...
            'XTickLabel',[],'Color','none');
ylabel(hR,'Spread(USD)');
linkaxes([hL,hR],'xy'); % To sync zooming, panning etc.
```

Here's the result:

[image]

---

### To use with `subplot`:

Here, instead of creating new axes using `axes` we might need to create them using [`copyobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html) instead (this happens because the `axes` command happened to create the new axes in the correct `Position`, which is the default `Position` for axes; in `subplot` the `Position` is not default so the previous trick doesn't work):

```
%% Definitions:
date = 1:10;
z = 4*randn(3,10);
z2 = 0.2*sum(z,1);
y = -8:2:8;
%% Create the figure:
figure(); subplot(2,1,2); hL = gca;
set(hL, 'ColorOrder', [0.83 0.82 0.78; 0 0.5 0; 0.47 0.67 0.19], 'NextPlot', 'replacechildren');
plot(date, z,'LineWidth',0.5); hold on;
plot(date, z2,'Color',[0.31 0.31 0.31], 'LineWidth',0.5);
%% Customize plots:
grid on
xlabel(hL,'Date');
ylabel(hL,'Z-score(residuals)');
hL.YLimMode = 'manual';
hL.YLim = [y(1) y(end)];
hL.YTickMode = 'manual';
hL.YTick = y;

hR = copyobj(hL,gcf);
hR.YAxisLocation = 'right';

title(['Spread and Trade Signals']);
legend(hL,'Z-score','Signal1', ...
'Signal2','Spread', ...
'Location','NE');

ylabel(hR,'Spread(USD)');
linkaxes([hL,hR],'xy'); % To sync zooming, panning etc.
```

Comment: Many thanks! It worked. However, what if I have to do 2 subplots?

Comment: @RSerrano My bad, it appears on the other axes (`hL`). Just change `legend(hL, ...` to `legend(hR,...`